# Letter spacing issue around hyperlinks and bold text

Tags: hyperlink, removing-whitespace, concrete5

I have this odd issue that has been plaguing my site for a few months. The site runs on the Concrete5 CMS. The issue is the letter spacing before and after hyperlinks and bold text are being removed. If I go to edit the page, the spaces show up normal and everything looks nice. However as soon as I save the page, the letter spacing is back to nothing. The only workaround I worked up was adding additional spaces around links and bold text, so I would add a double space before and after to get it to look right on the webpage. I have no idea what's causing this issue. I've poked around with Firefox inspector tool, but I've had no luck in resolving this issue. If anyone has any pointers I would be grateful!

This page is a good example of the issue. https://www.dakotacollege.edu/admissions-financial-aid/apply-financial-aid

Edit: example of step 5 from this page

```
<div class="step-text">
<div class="steps"><div class="step-number">STEP 5<p> June-August</div></div>
<div class="step-text-inner">
<p>Students who have enrolled <strong>and have accepted</strong> financial aid for the upcoming semester will be allowed to charge books and supplies, up to the amount of any applicable excess aid, at the Dakota College at Bottineau Bookstore. </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's a video to help explain the issue
https://youtu.be/O8267jreR-U

Alright just another update, I looked at your suggestions and didn't see anything uncommented or changed. A user on the Concrete5 forums did mention the issue is also on the demo website for the Pixel 2 theme that my site uses. So it appears to be a theme issue. I tested this on my test server by removing the theme completely, issue is gone. I've reached out to the Theme creator to see if he has a fix. Here's a link to my request.

https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/themes/pixel/support/spacing-issue-around-hyperlinks-and-bold-text

**Isolated the issue! Your comment was a great clue! There's an HTML Minify option in the Pixel 2 theme options that was causing my issues!**

Comment: It looks like the saving the content (saving the block edit form) removes the whitespaces. Is it only on the content block, or on other blocks too? Do you have overriden the content block controller? And which c5 version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the response! It affects HTML blocks as well for sure as each step section on that page is a HTML block. I'm running the latest release 8.5.4, it was an issue before I updated it yesterday. I don't think I'm doing anything in particular with content block controller?

Comment: Please add an example of one of your HTML blocks (a small one) to your entry question. Btw do you have packages installed, which override the controller of the HTML block? You would find it here: `<package_name>/blocks/html/controller.php`.

Comment: So I went back to the office to start poking around some more. Looking under the packages folder I went through each addon, for each addon only has a controller.php file for its own block. packages > accordion_pro > blocks > accordion_pro > controller.php

I added some HTML from Step 5 from that page. I'm going to restore the latest backup to a development server and start deconstructing my site to see if I can figure out what's happening.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with c5-8.5.4. What I see, and this makes your environment special, not only your HTML markup of the step items is all on the same line. All HTML markup on the page has this style. Looks like you have something, which removes some of your whitespace. My markup is on separate lines. Probably you have installed this addon: https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/minify-html?

Comment: Weird, I don't have that addon. I tried uninstalling some addons in my test environment, but it didn't yield much success. Is there steps I should try in my test environment to revert these issues?

Comment: There are several locations, where this could be implemented. Try a clean c5 installation. If the problem is not there, add a package and install it, try again, if you could reproduce. If not, install the next package. But before you do this, have a look into `application/bootstrap/app.php` if there are definitions (add them to the initial question, if there are unvommented definitions). Another location could be under `application/src/View` with a `View.php`file.

Comment: I will check those places out and give it a go! Thank you for your time and help! I will update tomorrow on what I’ve tried.

Comment: Isolated the issue! Your comment was a great clue! There's an HTML Minify option in the Pixel 2 theme options, I must have enabled that a few months ago. I disabled it, and ta-da! Problem resolved! Thank you so much for your help! It definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: yw, glad I could help.